# Should the iris of a Canonet QL17 contract at all in AE mode at maximum aperture?

Tags: canon, diaphragm

Note that you need to cock the shutter for the tests below, otherwise the iris doesn't fully engage with the aperture controls.

If I set my QL17 to ƒ/1.7, the iris opens up fully (as I'd expect)

If I put my QL17 into A mode and partially depress the shutter button (to trigger the exposure mechanism) the iris never opens up larger than (more or less) the aperture I can set manually with ƒ/2.

The coupling is mechanical, and though the repair manual doesn't mention it, there is an adjustment screw that turns a cam that regulates this.

On the light meter, there are two levers that rotate as the shutter release lever (part 19-0562) is depressed. One traps the other end of the meter needle to hold it in place, and the second follows to intercept the meter with a staircase profile at an angle corresponding to the needle's angle.

This part of the mechanism is not exploded in the repair manual.

The cam then determines the angle of the EE lever (13-5302) that determines the actual iris aperture.

I can adjust the cam so that in AE mode at maximum aperture, the iris is as wide open as it is at ƒ/1.7 in manual mode - but I'd be interested to know what the behaviour is on yours.

Comment: I am unsure that what you perceive as a problem is a problem. *I.E. an adjustment screw*.  In A mode the aperture is dictated by the info it gets from the light meter based on the shutter speed you have set.  This camera only uses the light meter in A mode, If you move it out of A mode to a specific aperture the light meter does not function and it sets the lens to the chosen aperture.  It is a range finder and it does not meter through the aperture opening, the iris/aperture does not affect the light entering the sensor.

Comment: I've explained it badly then. The issue is that in A mode, the aperture of the iris (when its setting is triggered by the auto-exposure system) is *never* larger than the aperture at the manual ƒ/2 setting. Whereas I would expect it to be, in appropriate circumstances. Unfortunately I don't have another QL17 to compare it with right now.

Comment: Are you saying that when in A mode you meter the scene and it tells you that ƒ/2 is required for the shutter speed   you have chosen and  then when you **actuate the shutter**   the camera uses an aperture other then ƒ/2 ?  In A mode, The camera will set the f stop to what the meter is saying must be used for the shutter speed chosen and the amount of light in the scene. **Why do you expect ƒ/2?**  In your scenario is the light meter telling you the camera needs ƒ/2 for the scene you are metering?

Comment: or is the meter telling you it needs ƒ/1.7 but the iris fails to open to ƒ/1.7?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this occur as a limitation on meter range in my own QL17.

The way it works is this: depending on the ASA speed setting for the meter, the camera may not be capable of shooting auto-aperture at "wide open" before the meter sensitivity bottoms out.  Use slower film and the meter can still "see" when correct exposure needs that addition one third stop.  In other words, for a given shutter speed, f/2 for ISO 400 may be too dim for the meter, and the needle doesn't drop the rest of the way (hence can't be trapped at f/1.7), but if you set the ASA dial to 200, the meter won't run out of range before getting to maximum aperture.

Adjusting the movement to open wider may result in 1/3 stop overexposure throughout the entire range -- which isn't a terrible thing; even slide films like Velvia and Ektachrome (famous for narrow exposure latitude) can handle a third of a stop more or less light than perfect exposure.

Answer (score 0):

Since f2.0 sounds a lot like f1.9, it is possible the exposure mechanism is adjusted for or from a Cononette QL19 rather than a QL17.

Alternatively, the mechanism might only be designed for full stops, since full stop based aperture designs are fairly typical for cameras of that era (late 1960’s). Using a full stop design, would simplify manufacturing by using the same mechanism for the different models in the line.

Considering that the shutter is in full stops, full stops on the automatic aperture makes more sense from a design/marketing perspective.

Particularly since we’re talking about a consumer targeted camera from more than fifty years ago. But the fifty years also lends probability to the “Frankenstein” mashup idea as well. Back then new cameras were often assembled using whatever similar parts were on hand. In the years since it was new, a repair could have used on-hand parts too.